# How to download a library files from pod?

Tags: ios, delphi, firebase, cocoapods

When I follow the Firebase installation on iOS, I must do:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

but I'm under Delphi and I don't have access to pod. Under Delphi, I need the library file (.a) with the header file (.h)

How to retrieve these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll to the bottom of the [Firebase for iOS documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks), there are steps for how to install without using CocoaPods:

> If you don't want to use Cocoapods you can still take advantage of the Firebase SDKs by importing the frameworks directly.
>
> 1. Download the framework SDK zip (this is a ~100MB file and may take some time).
> 2. Unzip and see the README file for which Frameworks to include in to your project.
> 3. Add the ObjC linker flag in your Other Linker Settings in your target's build settings.

Comment: ooh my god was so simple :( didn't see it !